# vbscript ms word find and replace text with hyperlink

Tags: vbscript, hyperlink, ms-word

I have some vbscript which uses find and replace to populate a signature template.  it works well but I would like some text to appear as a hyperlink.  I have tried various things but don't really know what I'm doing so would be grateful for any pointers.

```
Sub SearchAndRep(searchTerm, replaceTerm, WordApp)
WordApp.Selection.GoTo 1
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Text = searchTerm
objSelection.Find.Replacement.Text = replaceTerm & ""
objSelection.Find.Forward = TRUE
objSelection.Find.MatchWholeWord = TRUE

If objSelection.Find.Execute Then

  Select Case searchTerm
    Case "%ScannedSignature%"

      WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()

  PictureFile="\\bb01.com\bwbdfs01\users\Signatures\scanned\" & replaceTerm
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If fs.FileExists(PictureFile) Then
    Set objShape = objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(PictureFile)
  Else
    WordApp.Selection.MoveEnd
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
    wscript.echo("Could not find scanned logo")
    wscript.echo(PictureFile)
  End If
  Set fs = Nothing

Case "%LinkedIn%",
  'This is where my code will go to insert a hyperlink

Case "%TelephoneLine3%", "%TelephoneLine4%"

  If replaceTerm & "" <> "" Then
    objSelection.Find.Execute,,,,,,,,,,2
  Else
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
  End If

Case Else

  If replaceTerm & "" <> "" Then
    objSelection.Find.Execute,,,,,,,,,,2
  Else
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
    WordApp.Selection.TypeBackspace()
  End If

End Select

Else
  'Do nothing
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word, Hyperlinks are managed by *field codes*. If you press Alt+F9 in your document you toggle between field code and field result view. Manually insert a Hyperlink into a document then look at the field code, just to get an idea of what you're dealing with.

In the object model, the field code is "abstracted" for you so that you don't have to worry about the field structures, just use the `Document.Hyperlinks.Add` method. You don't show us an object variable for the document that you're using in your code, so I'm going to assume objDocument...

```
objDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Selection.Range, "http://testaddress.com"
```

would be the minimum. There are additional parameters for a subaddress, Screentip, TextToDisplay and Target - look it up in the Language Reference for more information.